# Tedious timeout PIVOT mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sql-server-2000, tedious

I have a disgusting PIVOT-like SQL query *(PIVOT-like as running SQL Server 2000)*.

It's selecting roughly 3500 columns *(probably a couple more)* with a `WHERE` clause where value is in array of 1000 elements.

**NOTE:** *The query runs fine in MS SQL Server Management Studio...it takes around 4 mins to come back with the full result*

```sql
SELECT prodIdxTbl.ID AS ID,
        prodIdxTbl.ProductID AS orProductCode,
        COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Manufacturer, '') + '-' + COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Partno, '') AS primaryId,
        prodIdxTbl.manufacturerid AS ManufacturerID1534,
        prodIdxTbl.Model AS Model1551,
        prodIdxTbl.Partno AS PartNo1581, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='CacheMemory1206' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [CacheMemory1206], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='ISA1207' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [ISA1207], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='MonoTonerLife1208' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [MonoTonerLife1208], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='SpeedMonochrome1209' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [SpeedMonochrome1209], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='RibbonLife1210' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [RibbonLife1210], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='DataRate1211' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [DataRate1211], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='1792x1344GraphicMode1212' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [1792x1344GraphicMode1212], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='HorizontalFrequency1214' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [HorizontalFrequency1214], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='ModemSpeeds1216' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [ModemSpeeds1216], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN (REPLACE(COALESCE(fieldNamesTbl.Text, '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fieldNamesTbl.ID), ''), ' ', ''))='ScannerResolutionTrueHorizontal1217' THEN attrsTbl.Data END) AS [ScannerResolutionTrueHorizontal1217],
    ...
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature4' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature4], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature5' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature5], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature6' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature6], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature7' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature7], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature8' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature8], 
    MIN(CASE WHEN ('Feature' + (COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), featureIdxTbl.Sequence), '')))='Feature9' THEN featuresTbl.Name END) AS [Feature9] FROM [Data_Build].[dbo].[ProductIndex] AS prodIdxTbl
        INNER JOIN [IT_Data].[dbo].[Attributes] AS attrsTbl
            ON prodIdxTbl.ProductID = attrsTbl.ProductID
        INNER JOIN [FieldConfig].[dbo].[systemFieldNames] AS fieldNamesTbl
            ON attrsTbl.FieldNameID = fieldNamesTbl.ID
        LEFT JOIN [IT_Data].[dbo].[IndexFeature] AS featureIdxTbl
            ON prodIdxTbl.ProductID = featureIdxTbl.Productid
        LEFT JOIN [IT_Data].[dbo].[Features] AS featuresTbl
            ON featureIdxTbl.FeatureID = featuresTbl.ID
        WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, prodIdxTbl.lastupdated) BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE() 
            AND prodIdxTbl.ProductID IN ('8200','8202','8203','8205','8210','8211','8212','8218','8219','8255','8273','8276','8277','8278','8287','8299','8313','8327','8417','8484','8499','8595','8596','8597','8600','8601','8602','8604','8608','8611','8612','8621','8625','8627','8629','8632','8634','8635','8636','8637','8638','8639','8640','8671','8677','8678','8679','8681','8731','8732','8739','8780','8783','8788','8791','8796','8798','8801','8804','8809','8833','8837','8852','8853','8855','8859','8872','8879','8880','8886','8889','8963','8965','8966','8968','8974','8975','8989','8995','8997','9000','9001','9002','9003','9004','9005','9006','9007','9009','9018','9027','9028','9059','9060','9061','9062','9063','9064','9065','9066','9067','9068','9080','9081','9082','9084','9085','9086','9087','9088','9089','9107','9108','9181','9189','9190','9191','9208','9210','9211','9212','9213','9214','9215','9216','9217','9218','9222','9223','9224','9225','9226','9227','9229','9230','9238','9250','9255','9256','9259','9260','9261','9262','9263','9267','9268','9269','9270','9313','9338','9339','9341','9342','9353','9373','9389','9394','9494','9496','9497','9499','9501','9519','9520','9523','9525','9527','9590','9592','9593','9600','9622','9623','9624','9634','9635','9638','9639','9640','9665','9688','9689','9690','9694','9695','9696','9703','9704','9705','9706','9707','9708','9744','9745','9747','9749','9751','9752','9753','9754','9786','9787','9788','9789','9790','9791','9793','9799','9802','9813','9822','9836','9837','9847','9872','9922','9923','9924','9963','9972','10004','10065','10066','10067','10068','10069','10070','10071','10072','10073','10074','10075','10076','10078','10079','10080','10083','10085','10087','10089','10118','10120','10122','10142','10146','10161','10183','10208','10213','10214','10222','10228','10233','10239','10242','10244','10248','10379','10563','10595','10603','10604','10606','10641','10643','10644','10648','10650','10673','10693','10697','10712','10713','10719','10720','10723','10731','10735','10738','10741','10742','10748','10749','10757','10760','10895','10899','10903','10904','10928','10929','10930','10931','10932','10933','10934','10935','10936','10937','10938','10939','10940','10941','10942','10943','10944','10945','10946','10947','10948','10949','10950','10951','10952','10953','10954','10955','10956','10957','10958','10959','10960','10961','10962','10963','11043','11053','11054','11135','11183','11185','11188','11189','11190','11191','11193','11194','11195','11196','11197','11198','11199','11200','11201','11202','11203','11204','11205','11206','11207','11208','11209','11210','11211','11212','11213','11214','11215','11216','11217','11218','11219','11220','11221','11222','11223','11224','11225','11226','11227','11228','11229','11230','11231','11232','11233','11234','11235','11236','11237','11238','11239','11240','11241','11242','11243','11244','11245','11246','11255','11256','11257','11275','11334','11774','11793','11794','11795','11796','11797','11798','11799','11800','11801','11802','11803','11804','11805','11806','11807','11808','11809','11810','11811','11812','11813','11814','11815','11816','11817','11818','11819','11820','11821','11822','11823','11824','11825','11826','11885','11886','11887','11888','11889','11890','11891','11892','11893','11894','11895','11896','11897','11898','11931','11932','12001','12002','12003','12004','12005','12006','12007','12008','12043','12073','12074','12075','12076','12077','12078','12079','12080','12081','12082','12083','12084','12085','12086','12087','12088','12089','12090','12091','12092','12093','12094','12095','12096','12097','12098','12099','12100','12101','12102','12103','12104','12105','12106','12107','12108','12109','12110','12111','12112','12113','12114','12115','12116','12117','12118','12119','12120','12121','12122','12123','12124','12125','12126','12127','12128','12129','12130','12131','12132','12133','12134','12135','12136','12137','12138','12139','12140','12141','12142','12143','12144','12145','12146','12147','12148','12149','12150','12151','12152','12153','12154','12155','12156','12157','12158','12159','12160','12161','12162','12163','12164','12165','12166','12167','12168','12169','12170','12171','12172','12173','12174','12175','12176','12177','12178','12179','12180','12181','12182','12183','12184','12185','12186','12187','12188','12189','12190','12191','12192','12193','12194','12195','12196','12197','12198','12199','12200','12201','12202','12203','12204','12205','12206','12207','12208','12209','12210','12211','12212','12214','12215','12216','12217','12218','12219','12220','12221','12222','12223','12224','12225','12226','12227','12228','12229','12230','12231','12232','12233','12234','12235','12236','12237','12238','12239','12240','12241','12242','12243','12244','12245','12246','12247','12248','12249','12250','12251','12252','12253','12254','12255','12256','12257','12258','12259','12260','12261','12262','12263','12264','12265','12266','12267','12268','12269','12270','12271','12272','12274','12275','12276','12277','12278','12279','12280','12281','12282','12283','12284','12285','12286','12287','12288','12289','12290','12291','12292','12293','12294','12295','12296','12297','12298','12299','12300','12301','12302','12303','12304','12305','12306','12307','12308','12309','12310','12311','12312','12313','12314','12315','12316','12317','12318','12319','12320','12321','12322','12323','12324','12326','12327','12328','12329','12330','12331','12332','12333','12334','12347','12348','12349','12350','12351','12353','12354','12355','12356','12358','12359','12360','12361','12362','12363','12364','12365','12366','12367','12368','12369','12370','12371','12372','12373','12374','12375','12376','12377','12378','12379','12380','12381','12382','12383','12384','12385','12386','12388','12391','12392','12393','12394','12401','12462','12463','12464','12483','12489','12491','12492','12493','12494','12496','12497','12498','12499','12500','12501','12502','12523','12524','12526','12528','12529','12530','12531','12532','12533','12534','12535','12536','12537','12538','12539','12540','12541','12542','12543','12544','12545','12546','12547','12549','12550','12551','12552','12553','12554','12555','12556','12557','12558','12559','12560','12561','12564','12570','12577','12578','12579','12580','12647','12662','12665','12710','12770','12775','12885','12909','13110','13111','13124','13128','13133','13137','13138','13139','13140','13141','13142','13143','13144','13145','13147','13149','13156','13157','13158','13780','13781','13782','13799','13817','13818','13819','13820','13821','13822','13823','13827','13829','13831','13834','13835','13836','13839','13841','13844','13847','13849','13850','13851','13852','13853','13854','13855','13856','13858','13885','13888','13889','13890','13891','13892','13893','13894','13895','13896','13897','13898','13899','13900','13901','13902','13909','13910','13911','13912','13914','13924','13925','13936','13937','13938','13955','13956','13957','13958','13959','13960','13961','13962','13963','13964','13965','13966','13967','13968','14261','14262','14263','14264','14270','14272','14279','14280','14281','14329','14330','14331','14332','14333','14334','14335','14336','14337','14338','14339','14340','14341','14342','14343','14345','14346','14347','14348','14349','14350','14351','14352','14353','14354','14355','14356','14357','14358','14359','14360','14361','14362','14363','14364','14365','14366','14367','14368','14369','14370','14371','14372','14373','14374','14375','14376','14377','14378','14379','14380','14385','14386','14387','14388','14389','14884','14889','14939','15015','15030','15045','15062','15093','15096','15098','15103','15148','15172','15173','15174','15177','15178','15179','15189','15191','15231','15232','15244')
        GROUP BY prodIdxTbl.ProductID,
            prodIdxTbl.ID,
            prodIdxTbl.manufacturerid,
            COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Manufacturer, '') + '-' + COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Partno, ''),
            prodIdxTbl.Model,
            prodIdxTbl.Partno
```

Sadly, we are stuck with SQL Server 2000 but if anyone has any ideas of simplifying this query then please mention it. I am quite rusty on SQL having been in NoSQL land for the past few years.

The `...` is just a placeholder for another few thousand rows of similar above it.

**`index.js`**

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const fs = require('fs')
const sql = require('mssql')

const { getWantedAttributes,
    getWantedFeatures,
    runQuery
} = require('./lib')

require('dotenv').config()

const ids = fs.readFileSync('./src/data/ids.json', 'utf8')

const parsed = JSON.parse(ids)
const idChunks = _.chunk(parsed, 1000)

async function init() {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: process.env.MSSQL_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MSSQL_PASSWORD,
        server: '<server_name>',
        parseJSON: true,
        requestTimeout: 300000, // 5 mins
        pool: {
            min: 1,
            max: 100,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 15000 // 15 secs
        }
    })

    try {
        const conn = await pool.connect()
        const wantedAttrs = await getWantedAttributes(conn)
        const wantedFeatures = await getWantedFeatures(conn)
        // Num of elements in query limited to 4096
        // Unsure how many Features there will be but 3000 is a safe num I think
        const attrsChunks = _.chunk(wantedAttrs, 3000)

        for await (const idChunk of idChunks) {
            for await (const aChunk of attrsChunks) {
                await runQuery({
                    pool,
                    chunks: {
                        attr: aChunk,
                        id: idChunk
                    },
                    wantedFeatures
                })
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

**`lib.js`**

```
exports.runQuery = async function({ pool, chunks, wantedFeatures }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = pool.request({
            stream: true
        })
        const sqlQuery = buildSqlQuery(chunks.attr, wantedFeatures)
        const arr = JSON.stringify(chunks.id).replace(/"/g, "'").replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')
        const queryEnd = `\n\tAND prodIdxTbl.ProductID IN ${arr}
        GROUP BY prodIdxTbl.ProductID,
            prodIdxTbl.ID,
            prodIdxTbl.manufacturerid,
            COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Manufacturer, '') + '-' + COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Partno, ''),
            prodIdxTbl.Model,
            prodIdxTbl.Partno`

        request.query(`${sqlQuery} ${queryEnd}`)

        request.on('recordset', handleColumns)
        request.on('row', handleRow)
        request.on('error', reject)
        request.on('done', resolve)
    })
}
```

I am using the `stream` property on the request as is highlighted by the [docs](https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#streaming) for large datasets coming back.

If I debug in VSCode all the way up to the query itself, the app hangs for around 20 seconds *(I presume running the query)* & then spits out this error:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=32621 index.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:32621/6c13f5a7-e858-43bc-ac87-aea8c616a1cb

For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

Debugger attached.

c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:94

  readTextPointerNull(parser, type, textPointerNull => {
                                    ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at textPointerNull (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:94:37)
    at readTextPointerNull (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:42:5)
    at valueParse (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:94:3)
    at next (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\row-token-parser.js:17:5)
    at value (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\row-token-parser.js:32:7)
    at readNChars (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:412:12)
    at dataLength (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:212:20)
    at awaitData (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:147:7)
    at Parser.awaitData (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:103:7)
    at Parser.readUInt16LE (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:144:10)

Waiting for the debugger to discon
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at textPointerNull (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:94:37)
    at readTextPointerNull (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:42:5)
    at valueParse (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:94:3)
    at next (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\row-token-parser.js:17:5)
    at value (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\row-token-parser.js:32:7)
    at readNChars (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:412:12)
    at dataLength (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\value-parser.js:212:20)
    at awaitData (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:147:7)
    at Parser.awaitData (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:103:7)
    at Parser.readUInt16LE (c:\Users\me\Documents\ProductAttributeRefresh\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\stream-parser.js:144:10)
nect...
```

My initial thought was that this is to do with the sheer size of the query. Specifically the evalled `CASE` statements but I don't know for sure.

What is the best way to go about this issue? Is there a way to further config mssql/tedious to get around this OR is there a better way to write this horrible SQL statement. If the latter, how?

Comment: `SQL Server 2000`, 3500 columns, a ton of casts, there's your problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am well aware... unfortunately it's out of my hands

Comment: *"Sadly, we are stuck with SQL Server 2000"* Why, out of interest? 2000 has been out of extended support for 7/8 years now; and been out of normal support for probably 11/12 years. You clearly know that 2000 is a hugely limiting factor here too; we can't work miracles with such out-dated technology.

Comment: In that case clean up the query, which btw is too hard to read. Do you need all those casts and checks for every single column? Or do you only need a null check?

Comment: Looks like an issue with tedious anyway. What version of that are you on? On this similar thread it suggest a later version may fix things. https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/issues/839

Comment: That ` COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Manufacturer, '') + '-' + COALESCE(prodIdxTbl.Partno, ''` in the GROUP BY means that indexes that may cover those columns won't be used. Group by the columns themselves instead. If you want to display a combined Manufacturer + Part number, modify the SELECT clause

Comment: @Larnu without going into too much detail, a partner company of ours is on an old _(very old)_ database server. This is their main db server which clients rely on & their philosophy is, "if it ain't broke, don't fix it"

Comment: But it *is* broke. That software is not patched, and has multiple security vulnerabilities. That is *broken*.

Comment: @wnash Another performance exterminator `CONVERT(DATETIME, prodIdxTbl.lastupdated) BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00:00.000' AND GETDATE()` means that no indexes on `lastupdated` will be used. Is that column covered by any indexes? Is it a datetime or a text field>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is what I am wondering whether I need those casts for every single column. The db table I am joining on for that _(the `fieldNamesTbl`)_ has columns on `ID` & `Text`. The value matching on is a concatenated version of both of these columns. I am wondering if it is possible to store this into a variable & not have to cast/eval everytime

Comment: @wmash as for how far broken that is, you could copy their entire "production" database into a single SQL Server Express instance and get performance improvements of several orders of magnitude. In fact, given that reporting on top of a production database is a very bad idea, you could just copy the data to a more modern instance and write proper queries. You'll be able to clean up the data while copying, fix types etc. How many rows are there in those tables?

Comment: @wmash Even SQL Server Express supports columnstore indexes, compression etc since 2016 SP1.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is not a bad idea to export their data to a more modern db. The issue is that the amount of data they hold is vast & is extremely convoluted. The end goal is to eventually get all their data out of such a very old system onto a newer, shinier, more manageable one. I think I might have figured a more manageable solution for the time being to not do a "pivot" & keep the number of columns as low as possible. If you want to post an answer of some sort then I would be happy to mark it. You've been a lot of help :)

Comment: @wmash define "vast". How many millions of rows per table? If those tables use IDENTITY for their keys you can copy only newer rows after the initial load. BTW SQL Server 2000 was used a *lot* for data warehouses, star schemas etc. It revolutionized data warehousing. People didn't query the OLTP tables directly, they copied modifications to properly designed star schemas, built one or more cubes on top of it and got whole-year aggregates in less than 1 second. What you try now will be slow even in a modern machine

Comment: @wmash the trick is to limit the number of *rows* you need to process each time and don't reprocess the data unless the source changes. This means you should only load modified rows, transform them and then store the transformed data in a reporting table. This way you won't have to pivot them again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the biggest table has over 2mil of records. I am not sure on the `IDENTITY` part of it. This db server was setup years ago _(I hope)_ & the schemas are not natural at all. For example, what you would expect a typical foreign key to be is not in the schema as a foreign key. Instead, the value was programmatically copied into each table using a lovely .NET script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would limiting the number of rows work? I thought the under lying issue was how many columns were being selected